# If x in array in Java

Tags: java

In python, you can use a very simple if statement to see if what the user has entered (or just a variable) is in a list:

```
myList = ["x", "y", "z"]
myVar = "x"

if myVar in x:
    print("your variable is in the list.")
```

How would I be able to do this in Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your array type is a reference type, you can convert it to a `List` with `Arrays.asList(T...)` and check if it contains the element

```
if (Arrays.asList(array).contains("whatever"))
    // do your thing
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] array = {"x", "y", "z"};

if (Arrays.asList(array).contains("x")) {
    System.out.println("Contains!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution,

```
String[] myArray = { "x", "y", "z" };
String myVar = "x";
if (Arrays.asList(myArray).contains(myVar)) {
    System.out.println("your variable is in the list.");
}
```

Output is,

```
your variable is in the list.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the array and search, but I recommend using the `Set` Collection.

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.add("x");
mySet.add("y");
mySet.add("z");
String myVar = "x";

if (mySet.contains(myVar)) {
  System.out.println("your variable is in the list");
}
```

`Set.contains()` is evaluated in `O(1)` where traversing an `array` to search can take `O(N)` in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling the Arrays class, you could just iterate through the array yourself

```
String[] array = {"x", "y", "z"};
String myVar = "x";
for(String letter : array)
{
    if(letter.equals(myVar)
    {
         System.out.println(myVar +" is in the list");
    }
}
```

Remember that a String is nothing more than a character array in Java. That is

```
String word = "dog";
```

is actually stored as

```
char[] word = {"d", "o", "g"};
```

So if you would call if(letter == myVar), it would never return true, because it is just looking at the reference id inside the JVM. That is why in the code above I used

```
if(letter.equals(myVar)) { }
```